# How can I make NativeScript open an email label in its native mail client?

Tags: email, email-client, nativescript

I have a simple page/screen. I want to be able to click the email address on the label when open the native mail client on the device. (i.e a **mailto:** equivalent).

I'm currently only concerned about iOS.

Is this possible?

**XML**

```
<Page loaded="pageloaded">
    <GridLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label text="sometest.mail@gmail.com">         
        </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can use the email plugin to do that:
[Nativescript email plugin](https://github.com/eddyverbruggen/nativescript-email) by Eddie Verbruggen

Comment: Can you do it out of the box?

Comment: Well I guess. You have access to the native API via Javascript, so, in theory, you could call the mail application passing the necessary parameters.

Comment: Are there any objections to using the plugin?

Comment: I decided to use the HtmlView instead. This linked up the email and phone call automatically. Thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 7):

Or you could open the default email app while using **openUrl** method from `tns-core-modules/utils/utils`

```
import { openUrl } from "tns-core-modules/utils/utils";

openEmail() {
    openUrl("mailto:test@example.com")
}
```